# Entity framework - history table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, history

I have the following 2 tables defined in a SQL Server database:

```
create table Project
(
Id int,
Name varchar(100)
IdIdentity int
)

create table ProjectHistory
(
Id int,
Name varchar(100)
IdIdentity int,
DtChange datetime
)
```

When I updated "Project" I would like to insert new record to table `ProjectHistory` with setting `DtChange` to actual date.

I use Entity Framework 4.1. Can you suggest me some way how this can be accomplished?
There is possibility change sql that generate Entity Framework when saving changes.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional way would be to use an `update trigger` on the project table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgProjectUpdate
   ON  Project
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    insert ProjectHistory (id, name, dtchange)
    select id, name, GETDATE() from deleted
END
```